# How to play a group of wav files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, wav

Let's say I have an Html file that look like this:

```
<div name="piano">
    <div name="a.wav"></div>
    <div name="b.wav"></div>
    <div name="c.wav"></div>
</div>
```

How would I play all the `.wav` files mentioned in the piano `div` simultaneously (when a button is pressed)?

Edit: For clarification, eventually the user will be able to select what notes are played and at what time. This is just a simplified example.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript, juse use the `<audio>` element. But browsers will block autoplay by default for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Dai No, that is incorrect.  The timing is not predictable with just the audio element.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, getting exact timing right isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

The normal audio element (`<audio>` or `new Audio()`) is not appropriate for this use case, as it leaves no method for precise timing.  You need to use the Web Audio API.

Use a `BufferSourceNode` for each note you want to play:

```
const buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(... audio data ...);
const bufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
bufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;
bufferSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
bufferSourceNode.start(/* you can use a start time here */);
```

See also:

- JSFiddle I made for a mini sampler:  https://jsfiddle.net/bradisbell/sc9jpxvn/1/
- AudioBufferSourceNode documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to play it randomly use:

```
    <audio src="..." id="song1"></audio>
    <audio src="..." id="song2"></audio>
    <audio src="..." id="song2"></audio>
```

```js
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){   
       document.querySelector("#song" + i)[0].play();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

With html5, you should use the `<audio>` tag. It have javascript hooks for 'play', 'pause', etc.

You can add the following html;

```
<button onclick="playA();playB();playC()">Play Audio</button>
```

with corresponding javascript

```
var audioA = new Audio('a.wav');
var audioB = new Audio('b.wav'); 
var audioC = new Audio('c.wav');     
function playA() {
      audioA.play();
    }
function playB() {
      audioB.play();
    }
function playC() {
      audioC.play();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, because the timing will not be precise.  In fact, there's no guarantee at all that these will play at the same time, since they won't even be loaded until the button is clicked.

Comment: I assigned the variables outside the functions. Is it good now?

Comment: No, the browser still typically won't load those files until playback has started.  It will pre-load metadata only.  Even if it did preload them, timing still isn't guaranteed.  Even if it were guaranteed, some browsers (particularly on mobile devices) won't play more than one at a time.  See my answer for the right way to handle this situation with the Web Audio API, where timing is guaranteed.