# Better timing for audio file

Tags: javascript, audio

So I created the audio:

```
const jumpy = new Audio();
jumpy.src = "./audio/jump2.wav";
```

and generated an event listener that triggers the audio:

```
const cvs = document.getElementById("ghost");
```

```
cvs.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
            jumpy2.play()

    });
```

the problem is the browser first waits for the audio to play in full (about 1000 ms) before it will play it again but I want the audio to reset every time I click.

How can I go for that?

```
const jumpy = new Audio();
jumpy.src = "./audio/jump2.wav";

const cvs = document.getElementById("ghost");


cvs.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
            jumpy2.play()

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For short sounds that you want to use multiple times like this, it is better to use the AudioBufferSourceNode in the Web Audio API.

For example:

```
const buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(/* audio data */);
const bufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
bufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;
bufferSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
bufferSourceNode.start();
```

The buffer will be kept in memory, already decoded to PCM and ready to play.  Then when you call `.start()`, it will play right away.

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355960/362536

Comment: thanks. Quick question though. What is the destination? Is that a placeholder term or a reserved keyword?

Comment: also, Im getting an error for using the await operator in this context: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules